# Array retornando dados repetidos PHP

Tags: php

Pessoal estou fazendo uma loja virtual e estou retornando os produtos do banco de dados para mostrar na minha vitrine, o problema é que no meus banco eu só possuo dois produtos "Maçã" e "Laranja", mas está retornando vários produtos repetidos, preciso que mostre somente os produtos que possuem no banco sem repetição no caso 2, segue imagens e o código que estou usando, desde já agradeço[image: Vitrine da Loja]

[image: Banco de dados]

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="display-4 mt-5 mb-5">Produtos<h2>

    <?php
    
    ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
    require_once '../class/conexao2.php';
    global $pdo;

    $query_prod = "SELECT id_Produto, Nome_prod, Desc_prod, Image, Preco_idPreco, Valor_prod, Valor_novo FROM produto, preco";
    $result_prod = $pdo->prepare($query_prod);
    $result_prod->execute();

    ?>

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">          

        <?php
        
        while($row_prod = $result_prod->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

            extract($row_prod);
            
        ?>
        <div class="col mb-4 text-center">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src='<?php echo "../img_prod/$id_Produto - $Nome_prod/$Image"; ?>'  class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo "$Nome_prod <br>"; ?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> R$ <?php echo number_format($Valor_novo, 2, ",", "."); ?></p>
                    <a href="view_prod.php?id=<?php echo $id_Produto ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Ver detalhes</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php

            
        }
        
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para prosseguir com a postagem dentro do objetivo do site é importante você [edit] a postagem e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Cara como eu iria fazer.

```
<?php
 $query = "select * from produtos";
 $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
 $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 for($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++):
 $dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
 $name = $dado['Nome_prod']
?>
<span> Nome = <?php echo $name?>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).